# How to disable swipe in damajia's AndroidImageSlider in Android?

Tags: android, slider, androidimageslider

I am trying to use damajia's [AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/wiki/Slider-view) and for my app I need to disable the swipe feature. From this [link](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout/issues/24), they say that the have included in setSwipeEnabled function. But when I tried to call

```
sliderLayout.setSwipeEnabled()
```

This function doesn't exist. So, where to call this function?

My gradle file is :

```
implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
```

Comment: You have to try this way: `sliderLayout.setSwipeEnabled(false);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override touch listener and not call their super whenever you want to stop swipe otherwise call it.

Comment: How do I override its touch listener?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make subclass of SliderLayout and override  OnInterceptTouchEvent that returns true. Use that  class instead of SliderLayout in your code.

```
public class SlideLayout extends SliderLayout {


    public SlideLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SlideLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SlideLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a boolean variable and setter in `SliderLayout.java`

```
private boolean isDisableTouchEvent = true;
public void setDisableTouchEvent(boolean disableTouchEvent) {
    isDisableTouchEvent = disableTouchEvent;
}
```

and replace `onInterceptTouchEvent` function with below

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (isDisableTouchEvent)
        return true;
    else {
        int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                pauseAutoCycle();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

after that you can disable swipe with this

```
slider.setDisableTouchEvent(true);
```